# Filter rows according to changes among sets of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

**I have the following sample data:**

```
LOCAN_ACCOUNT LOAN_VERSION LENDER PROPORTION PARAM_1
------------- ------------ ------ ---------- -------
            1            1 A             0.6 a      
            1            1 B             0.4 b      
            1            2 A             0.6 a      
            1            2 B             0.4 b      
            1            3 A             0.6 a      
            1            3 B             0.4 b      
...
...
            2            1 A            0.55 a      
            2            1 B            0.45 b      
            2            2 A            0.55 a      
            2            2 B            0.45 b      
            2            2 C               0 c      -- << Note the addition of lender C in LOAN_VERSION = 2
            2            3 A            0.55 a      
            2            3 B            0.45 b      
...
...
            3            1 A           0.555 a      
            3            1 B           0.445 b      
            3            2 A           0.555 a      
            3            2 B           0.445 bbbbb  -- << Note the modification of PARAM_1 for lender B in LOAN_VERSION = 2
...
...
            4            1 A           0.555 a      
            4            1 B           0.445 b      
            4            2 A           0.555 a      
            4            2 D           0.445 d      -- << Note the modification of lenders from B to D in loan versions 1 and 2
```

**Requirements:**

The expected output is:

```
LOAN_ACCOUNT SHOULD_BE_RETURNED
------------ ------------------
           1 Yes                
           2 No                
           4 No                
           3 No
```

When column `SHOULD_BE_RETURNED` is `'Yes'` when for a loan account, for all its loan versions, there are no changes in lenders, their proportions and `param_1` column. Loan account `1` in above example satisfies these conditions.

The column should be `"No"` when-

1. There is a new lender in any versions for a loan. There is an addition of a lender `"C"` in loan account `2`. Hence for loan account `2`, `SHOULD_BE_RETURNED = "No"`.
2. There is no change in any of the lenders' proportions or `param_1` values throughout all the loan versions. Note the change in `param_1` for loan account `3`. Hence for that too `SHOULD_BE_RETURNED = "No"`.
3. There should be no change in lenders. Notice the change in lender from `"B"` to `"D"` for loan account `4`. Hence for that too `SHOULD_BE_RETURNED = "No"`.

**What I have tried:**

So far I have managed only upto this but it also gives me the wrong output:

```
/*
WITH cte_loan_version AS (
    SELECT 1 loan_account, 1 loan_version, 'A' lender, 0.6 proportion, 'a' param_1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, 'B', 0.4, 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 'A', 0.6, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 'B', 0.4, 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 3, 'A', 0.6, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 3, 'B', 0.4, 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'A', 0.55, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'B', 0.45, 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 'A', 0.55, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 'B', 0.45, 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 'C', 0.00, 'c' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3, 'A', 0.55, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3, 'B', 0.45, 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'A', 0.555, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'B', 0.445, 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 'A', 0.555, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 'B', 0.445, 'bbbbb' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 1, 'A', 0.555, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 1, 'B', 0.445, 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'A', 0.555, 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'D', 0.445, 'd' FROM dual) -- */
SELECT lv.loan_account,
       CASE
           WHEN NOT EXISTS
                  (SELECT 1
                     FROM cte_loan_version lv_in
                    WHERE lv_in.loan_account = lv.loan_account
                   HAVING    COUNT (DISTINCT lender) > 1
                          OR COUNT (DISTINCT proportion) > 1
                          OR COUNT (DISTINCT param_1) > 1)
               THEN 'Yes'
           ELSE 'No'
       END AS should_be_returned
  FROM cte_loan_version lv
GROUP BY lv.loan_account;
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to aggregate the values together for each version, and then check if they are the same:

```
select loan_account,
       (case when min(lpp) = max(lpp) then 'Y' else 'N' end) as should_be_returned
from (select loan_account, loan_version,
             list_agg(lender || '-' || proportion || '-' || param_1, ', ') within group (order by lender, proportion, param_1) as lpp
      from sampledata
      group by loan_account
     )
group by loan_account
```